# Items do not place as wanted. [Java]

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a little game on my free time. It's a game where you can shoot on ennemies with your gun. 
But I have problems when I need to place the nozzle and the body of the gun. They do not place as I want and I didn't manage to find out why. The purpose is to have something looking like this for the gun :

[Wanted gun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jCFN.png)

But I have that instead :

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzbm8.png)

There is the code (var are in french (I'm Belgian) but I traduced the few  commentaries for you), I just dropped you the code you need:

Main.java :

```
package application;

import canons.Canon;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    private StackPane root, rootBureau;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;
    private Text titre;
    private Button solo;
    private ImageView imgSolo;
    private FlowPane rootJeu; // root for the gamespace
    private Canvas espaceJeu; // gamespace
    private GraphicsContext gc;
    private Canon canonJoueur; // player's gun

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        getRoot();
        getScene();
        stage = primaryStage;

        creerMenu(); // creating the menu

        stage.setTitle("Mad Java Guns");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void retourMenu() throws IOException { // deleting everything
        getRoot().getChildren().clear();
        getRootJeu().getChildren().clear();
        start(stage);
    }

    public void creerMenu() throws IOException {
        root.getChildren().addAll(getTitre(), getSolo(), getImgS());
    }

    public void creerInterface(String mode) { // creating gamespace (String mode isn't used yet)
        getRoot().getChildren().add(getCanvas());
        getGraphicsContext();
        getRootJeu().getChildren().add(getCanonJoueur());
        getRoot().getChildren().add(getRootJeu());
    }

    // Getters
    public Button getSolo() { // creating button for solo mode
        if (solo == null) {
            solo = new Button("Solo");
            solo.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                root.getChildren().clear();
                creerInterface("solo");
            });
            solo.setMinWidth(200);
            solo.setFocusTraversable(false);
            solo.setTranslateX(-300);
            solo.setTranslateY(-300);
        }
        return solo;
    }

    public ImageView getImgS() throws FileNotFoundException { // gets the pic related to the solo mode
        if(imgSolo == null) { // security
            imgSolo = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("imgsMenu/image_solo.png")));
            imgSolo.setTranslateY(-190);
            imgSolo.setTranslateX(-300);
        }
        return imgSolo;
    }

    public Text getTitre() { // title
        if(titre == null) { // security
            titre = new Text("Menu Principal");
            titre.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 20));
            titre.setUnderline(true);
            titre.setTranslateY(-380);
        }
        return titre;
    }

    public StackPane getRoot() { // main pane
        if(root == null) { // security
            root = new StackPane();
        }
        return root;
    }

    public Scene getScene() {
        if(scene == null) { // security
            scene = new Scene(root,1000,800);
        }
        return scene;
    }

    public FlowPane getRootJeu() { // root for gamespace
        if(rootJeu == null) { // security
            rootJeu = new FlowPane();
            rootJeu.setMaxSize(990, 495);
            rootJeu.setTranslateY(-149);
        }
        return rootJeu;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() { // gamespace
        if(espaceJeu == null) { // security
            espaceJeu = new Canvas(1000, 500);
            espaceJeu.setTranslateY(-150);
        }
        return espaceJeu;
    }

    public GraphicsContext getGraphicsContext() {
        if(gc == null) { // security
            gc = espaceJeu.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            gc.setFill(Color.BEIGE);
            gc.setLineWidth(1);
            gc.fillPolygon(new double[]{993, 7, 7, 993}, new double[]{7, 7, 498, 498}, 4); // creating borders of gamespace
            gc.strokePolygon(new double[]{995, 5, 5, 995}, new double[]{5, 5, 499, 499}, 4);
        }
        return gc;
    }

    public Canon getCanonJoueur() {
        if(canonJoueur == null) { // security
            canonJoueur = new Canon(Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
        }
        return canonJoueur;
    }
}
```

Canon.java :

```
package canons;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Canon extends Parent {
    private int posX = 500; // x position of the gun
    private int posY = 250; // y position of the gun
    private int tailleCorps = 20; // size of the body
    private Rectangle buse; // nuzzle
    private Circle corps; // body

public Canon(Color couleurCorps, Color couleurBuse) {
    this.getChildren().addAll(getBuse(), getCorps());
    this.setTranslateX(posX);
    this.setTranslateY(posY);
}

public Rectangle getBuse() {
    if(buse == null) { // verify if they aren't created yet. Security.
        buse = new Rectangle();
        buse.setWidth(70);
        buse.setHeight(20);
        buse.setArcWidth(15); // round extremities
        buse.setArcHeight(30);
        buse.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        buse.setTranslateX(posX);
        buse.setTranslateY(posY + tailleCorps/4);
    }
    return buse;
}

public Circle getCorps() {
    if(corps == null) { // verify if they aren't created yet. Security.
        corps = new Circle(tailleCorps);
        corps.setTranslateX(posX);
        corps.setTranslateY(posY);
    }
    return corps;
}}
```

If I haven't been clear enough, please feel free to ask me any other questions on my problem/code.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue? Where do you want the gun places versus where it's being placed?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the picture of what I'm getting. Edited in the topic.

Comment: Change `buse.setTranslateY(posY + tailleCorps/4)` into `buse.setTranslateY(posY - buse.getHeight() / 2)` to center the nozzle.

Comment: It worked, thanks !